# Resonant LC filters on a spherical capacitor

Tags: filter, resonance, resonant

In the setup below, the circles are plates of a capacitor, and there are two LC filters mounted on it.

Would the current prefer to pass via the filters if they are tuned to resonate at the frequency being output by the AC generator?

[image]

The circuit can as far as I see be simplified to the one below. The conductor between the filters is itself a capacitor plate.

[image]

The circuit can close across the larger capacitor plates, but the impedance will be lower through the resonant filter. And that is what the question asks about.

The circuit can sort of be simplified to the following. Or at least compared to it.

[image]

This can be seen [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmAHA6BOAzJbAWAdm2QQUMnxDOpH22oFMBaMMAKADdxNkVkqYXikJ9I4cAkzQwCfJnqRMYVPjDIGYcdqjQE7AMY8%20Qk8LD4q22JD74sUkqjZyS2VADYohlKlTHffwsrXTgxGzDIDw9sDyJIdQ9eKW8AGwDTAOQBKFDEEFZoZFFiYoR3IXwEP28AdwzLQPBGyHZ6tCDG90EWtpBu-uRxDsHtdmwKftV%20KgGScQgxieGazJH5iSXJ9aGAjcXvACc93bXRXI50gcyB7JCYeCQwIpL3SAQPZw8osC9Wo2uwmuLTyfGY9kwjnwqEIhEwkGc7wYrSAA) simulated on Falstad.com with the LC filters tuned to resonate, and be the preferred low impedance path.

Comment: I don't understand where the LC filter is; all I see mounted on your C is two L's; the C is dangling, only connected on one side, so this whole thing reduces to an AC source with two Ls in series, which can be simplified to an AC source and one L. You might want to draw an equivalent schematic to clarify what you're referring to! It will be relatively important how large the diameter of all this is, compared to the wavelength of your signal.

Comment: (there's really no filters here, the whole thing makes little sense, current doesn't "prefer" to pass somewhere but splits according to impedance / RF theory... There's so much unclear in here that I've decided to vote to close as "in need of clarity". No big deal, if you clarify things, clearly mark what the LC filters are you're referring to, draw an equivalent schematic and/or annotate with dimensions and wavelengths, I can retract that vote; but for now, this is all "hm, this makes no sense")

Comment: the filters are an inductor in series with one plate of a capacitor, and the outer circle is the other plate

Comment: no, as said, they're really not. As said, draw an actual equivalent schematic and clearly mark what you think are the filters

Comment: that you yourself vote to close it, is your choice, and feel free to act as you want (in general in life, I do that as well, I like free will and encourage it)

Comment: as I said, they are inductors with a plate in series. and, there is another plate opposite to them, the outer circle. of course, as there is dielectric in between, that acts as capacitor.

Comment: no, it doesn't. Your outer plate is connected to nothing. Please draw that equivalent schematic, and you'll instantly see the problem!

Comment: it is connected to nothing, by conductor, there is dielectric in between it and everything else. I see what you try to say, but the assumption is charge can move into and out of the outer plate, via the two filters, rather than a conductor directly attached to outer plate. if that is false, then, you can point that out, but does not seem false to me.

Comment: this question is unusable now as claims from Marcus are seen as true. but they really are not. the circuit can only be reduced to an AC source with two Ls in series, if the capacitor plates in series with the inductors transmit charge via the outer plate. since his false claims are judged as authoritative (they should not), I can not do much if the 3 moderators conform to that. here is a simplified circuit clearly showing what I stated is true, https://i.imgur.com/w5zlLUc.png, remove the smaller capacitor plates and there is nothing in series in a circuit (there is an open connection... )

Comment: It's false, pointed it out three times now.

Comment: Seriously, **draw the equivalent schematic** and you will see. Try it!

Comment: I am usually serious in what I do. an "equivalent circuit" for this has to take into account that the conductor is a capacitor plate. the simplest has been presented in pervious comment (what Marcus suggested it was is not a circuit, https://i.imgur.com/TypiMce.png. ) you make false claims, but if that is judged as authoritative by the 3 mods here then I cannot do much.

Comment: no, I don't make false claims (a bit rich of you, coming here for answers and then when you get remarks, claiming they're false, by the way!). I don't know what "3 mods" would mean in this context, but I don't think it matters. The schematic you've drawn is **not** a proper schematic. So, I'm really still not sure what you think happens here. I'll still give it a try.

Comment: it is not rich of me. there are simply true claims and false claims. and two inductors in series with an AC source and an "open" switch, that can be simplified to 1 inductor in series with AC source and an "open" switch, is not a circuit.

Comment: as stated, I can not do much if false claims from Marcus are accepted by 3 mods. but really, there is nothing wrong with the schematic I provide, or the simplified one provided.

Comment: seriously, what do you mean with "3 mods"?

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but your schematic is hopelessly wrong for the equivalent circuit of a capacitor.  A real capacitor is **cylindrical**, not **spherical** and you failed to show what "works" or your real measurements or design specs.  You now have -3 votes including my down vote for lack of clarity.

Comment: I don't mind having any bubble burst. I have argued as objectively as I can. you are now stating a spherical capacitor cannot exist. this is not supported by a scientific consensus. it is easiest if I can address false claims individually, so reflect on that one first.

Comment: Given that this is a distributed structure with capacitances inside capacitances, why are you trying to make Falstad (of all choices for a simulator) simulate something that's way beyond its capabilities? Use a proper field simulator and you won't need to needlessly argue with experienced users here about a lumped element equivalent that's irrelevant anyway.

Comment: @nanofarad  In Falstad the simulation is only limited by your imagination to realize RLC for every passive component and trace.  Mr. Thevenin does not realize what we know is true and cannot put his question into proper perspective of reality.  Spherical Capacitors are only experimental not real commercial types and his drawing is not spherical with primitive entry points.  Analysis of current at resonance will show he has no series capacitance. This question has no accuracy.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I am not arguing with your claim. I believe that if the OP does not understand the weakness of their inaccurate model, then they have no business trying to use that simulated model and must fall back to a field solver as it removes the inaccuracy of their modeling.

Comment: @nanofarad  This is what happened . His Logic Diagram is illogical with a concentric shield that lacks any connection to the generated signal.  But in reality there is a freespace capacitance which depending on size will reduce the value of said disconnected capacitor to the parasitic leakage C. The illogical circuit can be simulated on Falstad as it is capable of simulating any discrete RLC model in physics, but not with EM fields rather matrix voltages and currents, as long as the model is accurate, which it isn't.  U cant perform field solver on a 2D "sphere" with no dimensions

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what this is (it uses non-standard components,

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p2tq.png]

is **not** equivalent to your drawing.

Equivalent would be

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB8Wbv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and since the capacitor is dangling, it has no effect on the circuit whatsoever. So, this simplifies to

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDrDf6.png)</sup>

which further simplifies to

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPSArq.png)</sup>

which finally simplifies to

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffIKdQ.png)</sup>

There's absolutely no LC filter here.

Comment: You are still going by your false assumption. The capacitor plate in series with the inductors is opposite to another plate separated by a dielectric. This, you ignore. And then you simplify the circuit. I already shared a simple circuit showing your error, and your "answer" is only proving an equivalent circuit for your false idea about the circuit. But as stated, if the 3 mods that moderate this forum buy your false claim, I can not do much.

Comment: in your drawing, it definitely is *not* in series with the inductors. I've asked three times to clearly mark where you think your LC filter is, and you couldn't. It's simply not there. I don't understand what you're saying about "3 moderators". Moderators simply have nothing to do with all of this.

Comment: as stated many times. yes it is. you are still insisting on your initial assumption, that is false, and I have already pointed that out. the equivalent is similar to this, https://i.imgur.com/BjxkGYH.png.

Comment: @Thevenin I'm surprised to see how adamant you are at dismissing other people's help (you could look at Marcus's reputation, both here and on dsp.se, to give you an idea of what he's capable of, if not also browse some of his answers). If you look closely to your 1st picture, you'll see an L connected to ground and node #1 (let's call it that), then a generator from #1 to #2, then the *inner* plate of your cylindrical capacitor is connected to #2, the *outer* plate at #3, and lastly, another L from the *inner* plate, #2, to ground. Do you see now that #3 is floating?

Comment: I am not adamant at dismissing other people. I am pointing out that Marcus is wrong in his claim. there are many people here. what should govern is science. and if someone is objectively wrong, it should be the right thing to point that out, regardless of "rank" etc.

Comment: here is the circuit simulated, showing the low impedance paths, you can see the circuit simulated here, http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmAHA6BOAzJbAWAdm2QQUMnxDOpH22oFMBaMMAKADdxNkVkqYXikJ9I4cAkzQwCfJnqRMYVPjDIGYcdqjQE7AMY8+Qk8LD4q22JD74sUkqjZyS2VADYohlKlTHffwsrXTgxGzDIDw9sDyJIdQ9eKW8AGwDTAOQBKFDEEFZoZFFiYoR3IXwEP28AdwzLQPBGyHZ6tCDG90EWtpBu-uRxDsHtdmwKftV+KgGScQgxieGazJH5iSXJ9aGAjcXvACc93bXRXI50gcyB7JCYeCQwIpL3SAQPZw8osC9Wo2uwmuLTyfGY9kwjnwqEIhEwkGc7wYrSAA. as already stated, I cannot do much if the 3 mods conform to Marcus false claim.

Comment: I can at best argue using objectivity and the scientific method, and then not do much more, I do not control anyone else here.

Comment: @Thevenin Your simulation implies that the capacitor is in the circuit, which is not. That is Marcus's "assumption", which turns out to be true. If you want to insist that you are the only one right and the rest are wrong, so be it but, for the sake of argument, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbyFs.png) is what you need in order to have your circuit. As you've shown it in your 1st picture, though, the capacitor is floating, and Marcus's answer shows it.

Comment: What is your ax to grind with the '3 mods'? How is this at all relevant to any of this?

Comment: @a concerned citizen there is no circuit if you neglect the capacitor plate in series with the inductor. the claim that it is not there, well just look at the actual schematic I provided in my question. the claim is false. but if it is judged as authoritative by the 3 mods here, then I cannot do much. feel free, make your own decisions.

Comment: @Thevenin And even if you had the circuit that I've provided, you would not have tree capacitors, you would only have a series circuit comprised of two inductors (that can be combiined into one), a source, and a capacitor, thus a simple series LC. Also, to use the ping operator (`@`), use it with `@<TAB>`, the names should not have spaces, otherwise people are not notified; you get notifications because you're with the OP).

Comment: as stated, you now consider my original statement that Marcus claim was wrong. 2 hours have now been invested in it. the question is about amperage over the LC filters, reducing everything into a single capacitor and inductor and AC source makes no sense when analyzing that question.

Comment: I can only argue objectively using scientific method, and if there is some kind of "rank" system here that is superior to that, then, well, that is your choice

Comment: @Thevenin I'm very sorry that your drawing depicts something else than you think it does, but it's not anyone's fault, really. Could you maybe try to assume it does not show what you think it does? There's really not three capacitors in your drawing, at all, and they're not connected to the rest of the circuit. That's really not in the drawing! I sadly don't understand how you come to the **very** permanent impression that everyone else is wrong about it, but if we can't fix it, then we can't fix it, sorry.

Comment: your emotions such as being sorry are not objective, they are just your feelings. there are capacitor plates in series with the inductors. there is dielectric between them and the outer circle. that means they together act as capacitors. that is basic electronics. I can only argue based on simple scientific rules, and most people know that a plate that stores charge, opposite another plate with dielectric between, has capacitance.

Comment: yes, I know what a capacitor is. But, you don't seem to understand that as well, sorry. An outer electrode, not connected to anything else, **does not contribute** to the circuit, and hence could simply be omitted. Don't try to contradict based on "scientific method". What you're doing is namely the complete opposite: assuming something has an effect (which it doesn't), and not trying to understand when experts tell you why.

Comment: false. the outer capacitor plate is connected via dielectric. just like here, https://i.imgur.com/7tUYMtN.png, a more simple comparison. you have stuck to a false claim for 3 hours, and I can only argue objectively. the outer plate is "connected" over the dielectric.

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit won't work as shown as the generator is not in series with the capacitor.  The outer layer is just a shield and all you have is a conductor between two coils. The 2 coils could in fact be in series (2L) and attached to the inside making the outside lower EMI as ground.

I've shown it below another way.

[image]

Since there are only 2 electrodes, there is only 1 capacitor. (neglecting parasitic earth capacitance)

***This REDUCES DOWN TO A SINGLE LC filter.

Your diagram is simply 2 L's in series.***

Comment: The inductor is in series with one plate of a capacitor. It is a bit unconventional, since asymmetric and split up capacitors like that are probably not usually used. The other plate of the capacitor will be the outer circle, there is dielectric between it, that this is the case is clear. This means the AC source is in series with it. I simplified the circuit and provided a simulation showing that low impedance paths are preferred.

Comment: It is incorrect as you have shown otherwise the coil must be big or else melt. and there is no series C rather a tiny parallel C due to freespace not shown

Comment: if you argue it is correct if the coil is big, then it cannot at the same time not be correct. there is capacitance between the plates in series with inductors, and between the inner and outer circle, and the inner and outer circuit also serve as conductors. in that sense, there is series C. it makes no sense to claim there is not.

Comment: The outer cylinder has no conductor, therefore it is not a capacitor. You must be a rookie with no profile.

Comment: to make it easy to see what is discussed on this question, Tony is claiming it can be reduced to LC filter, and Marcus (and concerned citizen?) that it is reduced to just an inductor (and AC source). both claims cannot be true as they are not in agreement.

as for reducing it to just capacitance and inductance (like Tony argues), the point with reducing the circuit is that it still has to be able to answer the question. you can reduce a resistive network down to a single resistor, sure, but that does no good if you are interested in a certain point in the circuit.

Comment: It can be reduced to an LC filter with the change that I made.  Yours has no C connected in the loop

Comment: (answer to comment two above) neither does the simulated circuit equivalent I shared, yet it is working. the current through the outer plate is via the different capacitor plates opposite to it. exactly what people call asymmetric capacitor with multiple plates on one end, I do not know but there's probably a term for that.

Comment: If you claim something is working. Your model is inaccurate  Try again until you figure it out OR describe better what you did

Comment: the outer capacitor plate is connected via the dielectric, just like here, https://i.imgur.com/7tUYMtN.png, the circuit is completed over dielectric and not through conductor. the capacitor in the question is unusual as a standard component, but use basic electronics and you see it is as stated in question

Comment: I stand by my conclusion

Comment: FWIW, cylindrical inductance will be very low ~ 0.1 ~ 0.2 nH/mm depending on geometry

Answer (score 2):

A cylindrical capacitor consists of an inner conductor of radius \$a\$ and an outer conductor whose inner radius is \$b\$. The space between the conductors is filled with a dielectric of permittivity \$\varepsilon\$ and the length of the capacitor is \$L\$. Look at the figure below, taken from D.K.Cheng (pp. 125): -

[image]

The capacitance for such a capacitor is \$C=\frac{2\pi\varepsilon L}{\ln(\frac{a}{b})} \$.

If you want to use such a capacitor in a circuit to create an LC-filter, you have to connect the inner conductor to an inductor in series with a power source and connect the outer conductor to ground (or vice versa).